# Why am I getting undefined from a string that has data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So I am pulling data from my database using an API with this code:

```
let { id } = useParams();
const [Tenant, setTenant] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/tenants/byId/${id}`).then((response) => {
    setTenant(response.data);
  });
}, []);
```

I then try to set a default value on my Material UI textfield using:

```
<TextField 
    id="Field1" 
    defaultValue={Tenant.tenantName}
    label="Tenant Name" 
    variant="outlined" 
    onChange={(event) => {setNtenantName(event.target.value)}}
    required
/>
```

But, I was not getting anything. So I decided to `console.log(Tenant.tenantName)` and was getting this in my console:

[image: Console Log]

Comment: Because you're doing `Tenant.tenantName` and your state is initially an empty string that doesn't have a `tenantName` property. Your state is only set to your API data once your axios GET request completes (which isn't immediately and takes some time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Kevin is proposing should work well, but you can also do something like so, which it might be easier to read and will display a loader while is fetching the data..

```
if(Tenant === undefined) return <div>Loading data....</div> 
else return (
  <TextField 
     id="Field1" 
     defaultValue={Tenant.tenantName}
     label="Tenant Name" 
     variant="outlined" 
     onChange={(event) => setNtenantName(event.target.value)}
     required 
  />
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your state is not ready by the time you're trying to access it.

So you can check for it.

```
{Tenant && (
   <TextField 
        required id="Field1" 
        defaultValue={Tenant.tenantName}
        label="Tenant Name" 
        variant="outlined" 
        onChange={(event) => {setNtenantName(event.target.value)}}
        />
)}
```

also on a side note it's not common to capitalize your state names.

u can change it to : `const [tenant, setTenant] = useState("");`
just for convention